# how to query using LIKE in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with a bit problem while I'm trying to do a LIKE select query. Here's my code:

```
$products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE 
                         prod_name LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%'")
            or die(mysql_error());
```

which $search_text is user input. When I tried to input "sony" text for testing and run it, it showed me an error message like this:

```
Unknown column 'sony' in 'where clause'
```

I don't know where the mistake is. Can someone show me what's wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Tony

Comment: Please try `echo "SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%'"` and add the output to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid:

```
$products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Replace `=` with `LIKE`

**EDIT:**
Okaay. Now you changed it. Problem still persists?

Let me guess... Your `$search_text` is escaped with surrounding `''`?

Try echo that value and see what you get. You might be parsing something like `LIKE '%'sony'%'`.

If that's the case and your value is escaped automaticly, you can either do a

```
$search_text = trim($search_text, "'");
```

or a

```
$search_text = substr($search_text, 1, (strlen($search_text) - 2));
```

Comment: Based on the error, do you think there could be some kind sql injection type issue, like maybe he's wrapping the var value itself in quotes?  otherwise it's really odd that it's throwing a non-existant column error.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thoughs aswell. I've covered this possibility in my answer above. I'm just unsure whenever that error or incorrect structure error is shown in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is just a guess

You might be having the backticks  around the variable `$search_text`. check your query again and make sure that the variable is wrapped with either the single or double quote and not with the backtick.

backtick `

Answer (score 0):

A. I think you have sanitize your values

Try

```
$searchText = mysql_real_escape_string ( $search_text );
$products = mysql_query ( "SELECT * 
        FROM product WHERE
        prod_name LIKE '%" . $searchText . "%'" ) or die ( mysql_error () );
```

B. using double `%` is not an efficient way to search try use `LIKE '" . $searchText . "%'"` is  Better Approach

C. Run `var_dump($searchText)` to make sure you are its outputting the exact data you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Get idea from this line, I tried running on my db and working for me

```
"select * from product where prod_name like('%".$search_text."%')"
```

Hope this will help you.